# Business internet multiple external IP's to one internal network

Tags: networking, routing, nat

I have small business internet. Currently the modem they have given me has 4 ethernet ports on it. I would like to get a block of 4 or 5 static IP's from them but I'm wondering what kind of equipment do I need to do the NAT to have one internal network. I have a linksys router with DD-WRT on it but it seems incapable of performing this task. If anyone has done this or something similar I am open to all suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest checking out [PFSense](http://www.pfsense.org).  I have used this firewall quite a bit and it always seems to handle everything I throw at it.  It runs very well on an old pc or the ALIX platform of embedded devices.

With PFSense, you will be able to assign all of your IPs to the firewall.  From the firewall to can: port-forward to hosts in the internal network from external IPs, setup 1:1 NAT, or assign IPs to other networks attached to the firewall. Also, there is lots of community support for PFSense.

Comment: Ok i bought a computer installed pfsense on and I still can not get the multiple external ips to work with it. Is there a good like you have found I have been trying for nearly a week now with no luck just more headaches and downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that that modem acts **only** as a switch then you plug up the WRT into it configure the WAN for static IP and your set. I am also going to guess the rest will be for servers, all you have to do for them is plug them into the other ports and configure them with the other static IPs.

Comment: I am going on that assumption as well. Unfortunately the servers are virtual machines. I have however found a site where someone modified the iptables in dd-wrt to do 1:1. I think in time however I am going to just build an embedded system and put pfsense on it